# laravel - query date between always return empty result

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am using laravel 8 and I want to get ids between two dates form created_at column which is timestamp format I use the following code

```
    $ids=Visit::select('id')->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->input('from_date'),$request->input('to_date')])->get();
return response($ids);
```

but I get an empty result

I tired to convert the inputs to time using the strtotime() function but also I get the same empty result

```
    $ids=Visit::select('id')->whereBetween('created_at',[strtotime($request->input('from_date')),strtotime($request->input('to_date'))])->get();
return response($ids);
```

> the input type in view page is date

could you please help with the correct syntax

Comment: what you get in request->input('to_date')

Comment: echo $request->input('from_date')."  ".$request->input('to_date') print the following  2021-05-20  2021-05-21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format using carbon

```
$fromDate=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->input('from_date'));

$toDate=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request->input('to_date'));

  $ids=Visit::select('id')->whereBetween('created_at',[$fromDate,$toDate])->get();
return response($ids);
```